# Quickly create dependency properties in VS

Tags: .net, wpf, visual-studio, binding, dependency-properties

Is there any way to speed up creating dependency properties in Visual Studio? Like some template or refactoring option that will make dependency property out of normal one. Anything. I create a lot of dependency properties right now.

Answer (score 57):

The code snippet for DPs is `propdp`, enter that and hit tab twice, then cycle through the fields with tab and fill them in.

Answer (score 18):

**New(ish) versions of ReSharper**

Newer versions of ReSharper come with the [`dependencyProperty`](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/Reference__Templates_Explorer__Live_Templates_CSHARP.html#Live_dependencyProperty_CSHARP) snippet built in.  So start typing "dependencyProperty" and it should pop up as an option for you to select (with the tab key).

In my opinion, this option is preferable because it comes with better defaults and formatting.

---

**Old versions of ReSharper**

If you're using an old ReSharper but still want to use Visual Studio's dependency property code snippet (without downloading anything), type `PROPDP` in all caps and then hit tab once.

IntelliSense will come up with "No suggestions" but insert the code snippet anyway.

Answer (score 7):

As a side note, (and someone correct me if I'm wrong please!).

If you're using ReSharper, it overrides the default snippet/templating system and doesn't have a `propdp` equivalent as shipped.

I found a [ReSharper `propdp` snippet here.](http://weblogs.asp.net/alexeyzakharov/archive/2008/12/02/resharper-live-template-for-dependency-properties.aspx)

Comment: You are right! It was strange to me that VS does not have dependency property snippet. But it was resharper...

Comment: It has it but Resharper does not show it... See H.B.s answer.

Comment: 4 years ago it didn't

Answer (score 0):

I have, and still use these 5 dependency snippets which will add reference or value dependencies as selected. They were created for Silverlight (*it was hot at the time, you youngins*) but the code they lay down works in WPF and Visual Studio 2017.

[Helpful Silverlight Snippets](https://www.jeff.wilcox.name/2010/02/silverlight-snippets/)

Answer (score 0):

I want to note that at the current time it is better to use https://github.com/HavenDV/DependencyPropertyGenerator, the code will be extremely simple:

```cs
[DependencyProperty<int>("MyProperty")]
public partial class MyControl : UserControl
{
}
```